# MySQL Partial match in lists such as IN ('%sdfdsf%', '%sdfhjsdfh%')

Tags: mysql

Using MYSQL, how do I include partial matching in a `where` clause when I have a list of values that I want to search.

My initial try has been something like this:

```
SELECT sampleID, registrationNo, product
FROM Samples
WHERE registrationNo IN ('%23232%', '%45678%', %98764%');
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN` is a shortcut for simple equality tests. It is NOT a shortcut for `LIKE` matching.

These two are functionally identical:

```
foo IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
(foo = 'a') OR (foo = 'b') OR (foo = 'c')
```

With your wilcards, it's

```
(foo = '%bar%') OR (foo = '%baz%') etc...
```

If you want to use `LIKE`-type matches, then you'll have to write out every single `LIKE` operation yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have numbers (or simple strings), you can use REGEXP for this:

```
SELECT sampleID, registrationNo, product
FROM Samples
WHERE registrationNo REGEXP '23232|45678|98764';
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it all in one statement.  You will have to break it up like this:

```
SELECT sampleID, registrationNo, product FROM Samples 
WHERE registrationNo LIKE '%23232%' OR registrationNo LIKE '%45678%' OR registrationNo LIKE '%98764%';
```